# How can I get Tails to boot? (I've tried everything!)

Tags: boot, installation, tails

First I got the .img file and copied it onto a USB stick using the dd method as described on the website. It wouldn't boot.

Next I got the .iso file and copied it the same way. It still wouldn't boot.

Then I used Unetbootin to burn the .iso onto the USB (after formatting it as ext4), while reserving 4 GB for files (is that for the persistent data, or is it some extra partition?), and it took a LONG time, pausing for like 20 minutes right as it reached 100%. But it eventually finished, but still wouldn't boot.

No matter which way I tried it, the USB drive doesn't even show up in the boot menu. And yes, I can boot from USB, and it works great for anything which is bootable, except evidently this.

And the .iso can't be the problem because it runs fine in VirtualBox and I got use Tails to do everything it's supposed to do without error.

The only other thing is that I'm running in UEFI mode, Secure Boot is disabled, and I think I might have tried it in BIOS/Legacy/CSM mode at one point. In any case, it's running in VirtualBox even though I'm using UEFI mode. And it's Tails version 4.12.

So what gives?

Comment: I've always had good luck with [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/). You could give that a shot.

Comment: I considered it, and I might try it, but it only works in Windows, and ideally I want to use ext4.

I saw some video that said that I can use Universal USB Installer, so I might try that one next.

A different video said that I should put it on a DVD as the initial install and then put it on a USB stick after that, but I don't know why that would be.  But I can try that too.

But I wonder if maybe there was something else that I've overlooked.

Comment: I've also tried using Universal USB Installer, and it still won't show up on the boot menu!  How can I possibly get Tails onto a USB drive and boot it???

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Bolena Etcher util to create the bootable USB stick.  That's what the Tails group apparently now recommends.  It and Rufus both worked for me.  I made sure my USB stick was formatted as FAT32 btw.  And I used the latest Tails .img file, not the *.iso which didn't work immediately (might have been some other issue though).